# set background from imageview on button click - Android

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have an Imageview and a Button in my project, i want the button to set the image as homescreen background but when i press the button, it doesn't do anything, no errors or force closes,

Thanks

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }


 public void setaswall(View view) { // SET AS WALLPAPER BUTTON
     WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
     };
  }
```

Comment: You only have `WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());` where do you set the image? there is no code for that

Comment: use `myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)`

Comment: in your button click and you get more info if yo google search or search on stackoverflow

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_laucnher);` then `myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap)`  To know more read the docs and google search

Comment: i cannot use this in my code!! i want to set the image from the imageview!!!

Answer (score 0):

Get WallpaperManager by using

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

To get imageView bitmap and set as wallpaper, use

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Or if you have the image resource id (as in your code example) then you can directly use

```
wallpaperManager.setResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

Comment: imageView cannot be reoslved

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);